# Using Extension:Maintenance to generate sitemap MediaWiki

Tags: sitemap, mediawiki, site-maintenance

I'm using MediaWiki 1.19.2. I want to generate a *sitemap.xml*. Here's [the documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aGenerateSitemap.php).

We have to use a maintenance script to generate the *sitemap.xml*. So I use the [extension Maintenance](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMaintenance) but I don't know the details, how to do? Any one know?

Comment: The sitemap extension isn't in the list of supported scripts, so I don't expect it's possible.

Comment: It's not sitemap extension. Sitemap Generator is a part of MediaWiki, it's native code.

Answer (score 2):

The [Maintenance extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMaintenance) only allows you to run [a limited set of maintenance scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMaintenance#List_of_supported_maintenance_scripts).  This list does not include [generateSitemap.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aGenerateSitemap.php), so you cannot generate sitemaps using that extension.

Instead, you might be able to use the [MaintenanceShell extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMaintenanceShell), which allows you to run any MediaWiki maintenance script.  Of course, even better would be to switch to a hosting provider that allows real shell access.